# QGIS 3.0 - MMQGIS - Geocode. Inconsistent results

Tags: qgis-3, mmqgis

I have a .csv file I am trying to geocode using the "Geocode CSV with Google/Open Streetmap" tool in MMQGIS and I am getting inconsistent results using the exact same file with the exact same parameters.  In any case, the results aren't what they should be.  My .csv file only has 11 rows, so it is not a huge file.

I ran the tool 3 times using these parameters:[image]

and I received these results... 
First time: [image]

Second time: 
[image]

Third time: [image]

Finally I tried to change the "web service" to Open Streetmap and received an error with no results. The results seem completely arbitrary and none of them are the desired result.  Can anyone explain this?

Comment: You may need an api key for geocoding using Google's services.

Comment: Definitely try with an API key, as I've found weird results from the API when it is not provided, similar to what you are showing... adding the Key solved the issue.

Comment: Even with the API key, I got no results.  I will just use ArcGIS instead.

Comment: I have an API key and it always returns 0 results